How to make Kover create aggregated code coverage
I am trying to make kover create an aggregated code coverage file. I see that they made this PR to create that implementation a couple years ago, but I am not sure about how it works since the readme has been changed a lot since then since the link in that PR's readme change no longer works. The coverage for my system is currently generated like this.
container('gradle') {
  withSonarQubeEnv('Name-Sonar-Cloud') {
    shWithRetryOnGradleException("gradle: Sonarqube analysis", """
    ./gradlew koverXmlReport
    ./gradlew koverHtmlReport
    ./gradlew koverCollectReports
    ./gradlew sonarqube --stacktrace \
      -Dsonar.log.level=TRACE \
      -Dsonar.verbose=true \
      -DenableJacoco=true \
      -Dsonar.branch.name="main" \
      -Dsonar.projectName="android" \
      -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.htmlReportPaths="${env.WORKSPACE}/build/reports/kover/all/*.html"
      -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths="${env.WORKSPACE}/build/reports/kover/all/*.xml"
      """)
      uploadCodeCoverageToS3()
  }
}

I have tried moving the koverCollectReports that to the beginning but that fails since it requires the html or xml files to exist initially. I think I should be able to use this command to modify the output? I found it the current readme but the workflow is completely different from mine so I am not sure how to add it
coverage-overall - [integer] The overall coverage of the project

